# CSS Transitions in React - fade in text when user clicks a button

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

I have the following presentational component:

```
const HowToControls = props => {
  return (
    <div className="col-md-6 how-to">
      {props.isOpen ?
        <p className={`text ${props.isOpen ? 'visible' : ''}`}>
         lorem ipsum............
        </p>/>
        : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The paragraph has class named "text" and a second class is added conditionally if the button in its parent component is clicked. The text is toggling, the inspector shows that both classes("text" and "visible") are added to the element, but there is no transition effect. Here is my CSS:

```
.text {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 600ms;
}

.text.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I guess that both classes are added when the page loads (before the component is mounted). Is that correct? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have the if statement `props.isOpen` before the paragraph. So technically it doesn't matter about the class change. Based on the `props.isOpen` it is either going to show the paragraph with the visible class enabled, or its showing `null`.
Try this instead:

```
<div className="col-md-6 how-to">
    <p className={`text ${props.isOpen ? 'visible' : ''}`}>
     lorem ipsum............
    </p>/>
</div>
```

For transition to work, it first needs to be in the DOM with an initial CSS property, and when that property gets changed or overridden it triggers your transition. In your case, you basically not even rendering the paragraph due to the having that conditional before the paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, that works for making the transition effect. My final goal is to make the transition when element is rendered for the first time. Is that possible without using an external lib?

Comment: @Naple just do a setState on your componentDidMount,.  You will of course need to convert into a React.Compoent, instead of plain function.